# Room Reservation System Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following association

```
User:   
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :rooms, through: :reservations
Room:
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations
Reservation:
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :user
```

In my reservation model I have following fields

> checkin_date, checkout_date

I want to find out all rooms that are not already reserved during the given time.

I have written following query but it's not working. Please suggest correction or better way.

```
    Room.joins('LEFT JOIN reservations ON reservations.room_id = rooms.id').where.not(
       'reservations.checkin_at < :requested_end_date AND 
        reservations.checkout_at > :requested_start_date', 
        requested_start_date: date_begin, 
        requested_end_date: date_end
    )
```

Comment: something errors ?

Comment: @BartekGładys It's returning empty when there is no reservation, it should return all rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations

  def self.find_unreserved date_begin, date_end, category 
    reserved_room_ids = Reservation.on(date_begin, date_end).pluck('DISTINCT room_id')
    if reserved_room_ids.empty?
      where(category: category)
    else
      where('id NOT IN ?', reserved_room_ids).where(category: category)
    end
  end

end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :user


  scope :on, -> (checkin_date, checkout_date) {where('checkin_at > ? AND checkout_at < ?', checkin_date, checkout_date) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
Room.joins('left join reservations on reservations.room_id = rooms.id')
           .where('reservations.checkin_at > ? AND reservations.checkout_at < ?', date_begin, date_end)
           .where('reservations.room_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: In this case, it wont show rooms with reservations but for another date.

Comment: the ranges were wrong (i just fixed that...) but don't get it, you want to get the room that are not associated with a user (reservation)... i think my query  retrieve that... (i guess)

Comment: I want rooms that are not reserved for a time period. There can be a case when room is reserved for a time period but free for given time period..